# Bulk with Concat (Upload all images from a folder)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a little bit of trouble with the function Bulk, I'm not sure how to do it. So, I need to upload all the images that I have in one folder into one table, I can upload 1 image with the next code:

```
Insert into ImageTest(ID, Imagen)
SELECT 'SQL Server Image', *
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK N'C:\Users\G11904\Pictures\Students\0001.PNG', SINGLE_BLOB) image;
```

ImageTest only has 2 columns, ID which is an NVARCHAR. The ID is going to save the name of the image. Imagen is an Varbinary, which is where I'm going to store my image.

I have ten images on my folder right now (Later on I will have like a thousand images).

My folder where I have all my images:
[image: My folder where I have all my images]

So I try the next code to try to store all the images:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;
DECLARE @cntImage INT = 1;
WHILE @cnt < 3000
BEGIN
Insert into ImageTest(ID, Imagen)
SELECT 'SQL Server Image', *
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK CONCAT(N'C:\Users\G11904\Pictures\Students\000', @cntImage, '.PNG'), SINGLE_BLOB) image; 
SET @cntImage = @cntImage + 1
END
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Incorrect syntax near CONCAT.

Can someone help to try and solve this issue? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: which version of sql are you using ?

Comment: Add ( before concat and check

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2014, Version 12.0.2269.0

Comment: I already try to add ( before the Concat.

Comment: I am sure you can not concat openrowset query, u have to use dynamic sql

Comment: Similar question posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621579/t-sql-issue-with-string-concat,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use *dynamic query*;

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;
DECLARE @cntImage INT = 1;
declare @query nvarchar(1000)
declare @imagePath nvarchar(1000)
WHILE @cnt < 3000
BEGIN
set @imagePath  = CONCAT(N'C:\Users\G11904\Pictures\Students\000', @cntImage, '.PNG')
set @query = 
    'Insert into ImageTest(ID, Imagen)
    SELECT ''SQL Server Image'', *
    FROM OPENROWSET (BULK '''+@imagePath+''', SINGLE_BLOB) image; '
    print @query
    exec sp_executesql @query
    SET @cntImage = @cntImage + 1
END
```

`OPENROWSET` expects string. You can't pass a variable.